# Block all non VPN traffic on DD-WRT

Tags: iptables, router

I have a router with DD-WRT installed. Just got Open VPN configured on it. Works great.

I would now like to make it so that if the VPN tunnel goes down all traffic is blocked, nothing besides the VPN connection itself should ever go directly to the ISP. That is, the router should only allow communication going through the VPN.

Reading on several blogs I arrived at this line of code:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o eth1 -j DROP
```

Which I have added to both startup and Firewall. But  it does not seem to work. I have disabled the VPN and am still writing this question.

This is what I currently have. Which after several reebots does absolutely nothing.
[image]

If it matters, it's a Asus RT-N16 router running firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/20/11) mega

Current bridge (more if it helps info).
[image]

**EDIT:** I got this to work using the following firewall commands:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o vlan2 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i tun0 -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Wrote an article detailing how to use it in DD-WRT with OpenVPN to block all non VPN traffic here: http://syntaxwarriors.com/p/1019/How-to-use-DD-WRT-to-connect-to-a-VPN-and-block-all-non-VPN-traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have OpenVPN as the endpoint on the wrt? The FORWARD rule won't affect traffic originating on the Asus itself, only traffic which is sent on/over a different interface in which the Asus needs to route for. [This Netfilter diagram can be helpful](http://accelazh.github.io/network/Play-With-iptables)

Example (on your Linux workstation): add a logger for port 80 going out your WAN interface (might be `eth0` on yours, I run a `br0` bridge for virtulization):

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -o br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix="FWD: "
```

Now connect to a server which uses port 80

```
# wget -q www.google.com -O /tmp/out.htm
```

Check your *FORWARD* chain:

```
# iptables -nvL FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      br0     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "FWD: "
```

Nothing.. `dmesg` is also quiet:

```
# dmesg | grep FWD:
```

Nothing shows.. so now try the OUTPUT chain instead:

```
# iptables -I OUTPUT -o br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix="OUT: "
```

After you repeat the wget, you should now see this:

```
    # dmesg | grep OUT
...
    [427898.519765] OUT: IN= OUT=br0 SRC=192.168.1.6 DST=72.21.91.29 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=62284 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58982 DPT=80 WINDOW=242 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Dropping egress TCP everything now becomes a simple rule which could look like this. You could also leave out the `-p tcp` to block any IP traffic this is just an example:

```
# iptables -I OUTPUT -o br0 -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

# wget www.google.com -O /tmp/foo
converted 'http://www.google.com' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://www.google.com' (UTF-8)
--2017-02-14 12:38:00--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 216.58.192.132, 2607:f8b0:4009:80c::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|216.58.192.132|:80... failed: No route to host.
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4009:80c::2004|:80... failed: Address family not supported by protocol.
```